# C# WinForm Stop control property setting to default when it is set to be a value which is also the default

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

The problem is best explained through an example:
I have a UserControl which has a default margin of 0, however I have an instance of the control which needs a margin of 3. I can set the margin of the control to be 2, 4, 10, or any other value other than 3 - but because 3 is the default value for margins in winforms - Visual Studio assumes I'm trying to reset the control to inherit the default value. This is obvious through the way the properties go bold:

When set to 5, the values are bold and the margin is set to 5:
[image]

However, when I set it to 3, Visual Studio assumes I want to "reset" the value to its default (note the property text is no longer in bold):

[image]

Unfortunately, for this UserControl, the default value is actually 0 - so setting it to 3 actually sets the margin to 0 at run-time. I need to set the value to be 3 like I can with any other integer

Comment: Why not set it in the code behind, on initializing the element?

Comment: A possible route, but it shouldn't be necessary. Setting the margin should be possible in designer view

Comment: how did you manage to have 2 default values for a single property?

Comment: 3 isn't actually the default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override `DefaultMargin` property of the user control:

```
protected override Padding DefaultMargin
{
    get { return new Padding(0); }
}
```

The default value for this property comes from `CommonProperties.DefaultMargin` which is internal and is `Padding(3)`.

Comment: Absolute legend

Comment: Didn't work. I see the value is set but not applied on rendering the control.

Comment: @Byju The question is a special case for the OP. Are you sure you are trying the same special case?